# Need to read a text file and write to a new one

Tags: java

So I have this code where it prompts the user to type in a file name for the input file and the file name for the output file. I have a string called 'names' which will then be stored into the input file that was created by the user. I've got this part down.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.SourceTree;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(chooseFile("input"));
    FileWriter writer2 = new FileWriter(chooseFile("output"));
    String separator = String.format("%n");
    for(String name: names){
        writer.write(name);
        writer.write(separator);
    }


    }

}

public static File chooseFile(String type) {
    String fname = null;

    }

    return file;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like so should modify your names list to all caps.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names[i] = names[i].toUpperCase();
    // writer2.write(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but what I still don't understand is how would I read the input file? and output the uppercased ones to the output file?

Comment: @user3496266 You could use the PrintWriter class and pass it the directory to a file, then instead of doing `System.out.println("Whatever")`, you could do `printWriterName.println("Whatever");`

Comment: @user3496266 Hint: A `File`**`Writer`** doesn't "read" anything. It only writes.

Comment: Besides; I trust your ability to search on StackOverflow for "read a file in Java".

Comment: Yes I know how to read a file but the problem is when I try to create a scanner in the if statement like so:
Scanner sc = new Scanner(writer); so that it reads the file created in writer.. it just gives me an error (red line under writer)